# List data was processed as a GenericType in Flink

Tags: state, apache-flink

I am new flink and want to process List as Tuple like `Tuple8<String, String, String, String List<String>,List<String>,List<String>,List<String>>`.
But when I submit my job to Flink k8s operator, "Tuple field #8 of type 'List' will be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance and schema evolution." logs have printed in console.

`ValueState<Tuple8<String,String,String,String,List<String>,List<String>,List<String>,List<String>>> state;`

I tried using TypeInformation like `state = getRuntimeContext().getState( new ValueStateDescriptor<>("state", TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple8<String,String,String,String,List<String>,List<String>,List<String>,List<String>>>() {})));`
But I encounted same log. Also I separated into each valueState, but I want to use just one variable. Because ListState is not supported `delete` method, and I have to use it.